# How to show a progress bar dialog irrespective of what happens in background UI

Tags: android

I have 3 activities interlinked to each other. By clicking an aspect of 1 st activity i will navigate to 2nd one, and on clicking an aspect of second i will go to third. The problem is it's taking a lot of time and the screen freezes. My program is too big to include the AsyncTask. Is there anyway of showing a progress dialog like "please wait" when i navigate from an activity to another. It will be much user friendly than a non-responsive screen.And i mean till the content of the new activity is displayed.

Comment: Just a thought ... did you ever consider using a `ViewPager` and move your code from the `Activities` to `Fragments` ? This way all 3 will run in the same activity, making the switch between them smooth and without a delay.

Comment: simply display an alertDialog in the start of `onCreate` & dismiss it as your view is loaded completely at the end of `onCreate()`..!!

Answer (score 1):

If you move from Activity1 to Activity2 and

- **your app freezes on `Activity1`**, then why just not have an overlay on each `Activity`, a simple `TextView` with `match_parent` on each side, and some text which initially is set to `Visibility.GONE` and before you start the next `Activity` you just set the visibility to `Visibility.VISIBLE` ?

You can reset the visibility back to `GONE` in `onStart` 
(i.e. when you press back on Activity 2 and come back to Activity 1, on Activity 1's `onStart` you set the visibility to `GONE`)

- **your app freezes on `Activity2`**, then set the `TextView` to visibile by default in your `xml` and then set the visibility to `GONE` once your finish whatever it is that freezes the screen.

I recommend using a simple `TextView` instead of a `ProgressBar` as you said that the app freezes, so if it freezes I'm presuming the `ProgressBar` won't animate itself, so no use in having moving parts for this.

Comment: it's a good idea. but I am not allowed to do it that way. This is for a Company and they have strict standards about application UI..

Comment: can you change everything to a ViewPager? Move all the functionality from the Fragments to Activities? Or is that not "allowed" as well? It would not influence the UX/UI at all ...

Comment: another question ... why does it freeze? What are you doing that makes it freeze? Can you not run that code after onResume is called. Or can you move your stuff to another thread, use an AsyncTask and use onProgressUpdate to send just the necessary data to the UI thread ?

Comment: It used to freeze when link was called in the activity.. Since at the start off every activity a link was called, It appeared as if the application as a whole was freezing.. but with asyncTask it is working.

Comment: Nice job. I'm glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Declare an AsyncTask, then simply display `ProgressDialog` on preExecute of AsyncTask. Do the time consuming and application freezing things like retrieving data from Link on doInBackground. Do the post Link retrieved works in the onPostExecute of asyncTask and dismiss the `ProgressDialog. AsyncTask runs on a diffrent thread from the main activity and hence the application doesn't freeze.

```
// ASYNC TASK
    class ClassName extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading ...",
                    false, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Your Code
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

            if (progress != null) {
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```